# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method Button.setOnClickListener

Tags: methods, nullpointerexception, listener, virtual

i am trying to solve this issue since a few ours now but i do not get a solution. I need you help pls. My App crashes with following error message:

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.u0017007.firsthaus.ZweitePage.onCreate(ZweitePage.java:26)**

Here is my Main:

```
package com.example.u0017007.firsthaus;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;  
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Android Button erzeugen
    Button buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);

    //Dem Button einen Listener zuweisen
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Toast ausgeben
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button erfolgreich gelickt :D ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Intent erzeugen, welches eine neue Activity (zweite Seite aufruft)
            Intent zweiteSeiteaufrufen = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ZweitePage.class);
            startActivity(zweiteSeiteaufrufen);
        }




    });



};


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



}
```

**And here is my second Activity where the error occurs in line 26:**

```
public class ZweitePage extends AppCompatActivity {



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//Button erzeugen
Button ButtonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
//Dem Button einen Onclicklistener zuweisen

##LINE26##     ButtonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent dritteSeiteaufrufen = new Intent(ZweitePage.this,DrittePage.class);
        startActivity(dritteSeiteaufrufen);
   }
});

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, `NullPointerException` means that the `ButtonBack` is pointing to a null reference, meaning that you should really be debugging line `Button ButtonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);` which obviously did not find the button you wanted to refer.

Check if there really is the button with id `R.id.buttonBack` in the proper view.

Comment: Thank you, problem is solved. I forgot to link the according xml-file in java code!